# What is the difference of the add and offer methods of Java's PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, collections

In [java.util.PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) we have the methods `add(E e)` and `offer(E e)`. Both methods are documented as:

> Inserts the specified element into this priority queue.

What are the differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference is that `offer()` will return `false` if it fails to insert the element on a size restricted [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), whereas `add()` will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

You should use `offer()` when failure to insert an element would be normal, and `add()` when failure would be an exceptional occurrence (that needs to be handled).

Answer (score 6):

To find out the difference, one needs to follow [PriorityQueue API javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) which in turn have "Specified By" sections that refer reader to respective methods in `Queue` interface:

- [Queue.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add%28E%29)

  > Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning true upon success and **throwing an IllegalStateException if no space is currently available**...
  >   Returns: `true` (as specified by [Collection.add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29))
  >   Throws: `IllegalStateException` - if the element cannot be added at this time due to capacity restrictions...
- [Queue.offer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer%28E%29)

  > Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions. **When using a capacity-restricted queue, this method is generally preferable to add(E), which can fail to insert an element only by throwing an exception**...
  >   Returns: `true` if the element was added to this queue, else `false`...

Both methods are present because these are required to be implemented by declared interface.

Note that since PriorityQueue is unbounded (as stated in javadocs: "*unbounded* priority queue based on a priority heap..."), preference of API designers expressed above do not apply. This means it is left at programmer discretion to pick the method that better suits their needs in a specific usage context.

Comment: Pffft you went and looked at the docs. Weak. ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos next thing you'll see would be me [complaining like Col Shrapnel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773) :) _oh you can't compete with 30-seconds answers: a question will get 5 answers before you can even find an appropriate link blah blah_